# select first div of mutliple div with same class name

Tags: css

Anyone know how to select first div of mutliple div with same class name

```
<div class="abc"><a><img src=""></a></div>
<div class="abc"><a><img src=""></a></div>
```

how can i select first img in css?

Comment: You'll need javascript. The is no `nth-of-class` selector.

Comment: @Paulie_D: why javascript?

Comment: exactly..why javascript?? this is a simple css solution

Comment: No...it isn't....there is no `nth-of class` selector. In certain circumstances you could use `nth-of-type/child` but that has **nothing** to do with the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first-child` pseudo class

```css
.abc:nth-of-type(1)
{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:red
  }
```

```html
<div class="abc"><a><img src=""></a></div>
<div class="abc"><a><img src=""></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div:nth-of-type(1)  {
   color: white;[enter link description here][1]
 }
```

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ffss3ke0/1/)**

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: if i use abc:nth-of-type (1), it is not work